# Page is loaded before API Call on React

Tags: reactjs

I'm new on React, I'm trying to create a ProtectedRoute which only load if i receive true from a API Call, otherwise will be redirected to a different page.
The issue is that the page load first and then the API is called.

1. The Blue part is the call to the API to obtain the "hasAccess" variable which can be true or false
2. the details of the routes I have and the ProtectedRoute one.
3. When I set the values of auth manually to True or false it works as expected but when I set the value of auth={hasAccess} then it always return false because the API is called after the page is loaded.
   [code snippet screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mw922.png)

Comment: Please do not post images of code, anything text-based should be posted as text directly in the question itself and formatted properly as a [mre]. You can get more [formatting help here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). You can also read about [why you shouldn't post images/links of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: Hi Julio, sorry for that. I won't do that again, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
const [hasAccess,setAccess] = useState(false)l

// set Access inside the useEffect

<ProtectedRoute path='/protected_path' component={hasAccess? Protected:''}>
```

Comment: I did that but Still the same, the  hasAccess comes as false always because the useEffect runs when the page is already loaded. when debugging I can see that the API returns true and setAccess as true but since the page is already loaded is taking it as false.

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. Future readers will be grateful to see explained *why* it answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code.

Comment: Hi Gert, thanks for the advice. I will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

"then it always return false because the API is called after the page is loaded." - It is not because the API is called after the page is loaded, since the API can't even be called before as the call in itself is part of the page (considering it is a single-page application).

If you want to prevent `protected` from being rendered before the API call is returned, then you should render it conditionally:

```
<ProtectedRoute path="/protected-path" component={hasAccess ? protected : undefined} />
```

or

```
{hasAccess && <ProtectedRoute path="/protected-path" component={protected} />}
```

Comment: Hi Lucas, thanks for taking your time to answering, I tried what you comment but no luck, I would like to add also that: <ProtectedRoute path="/protected" component={protected} auth={hasAccess} /> this vaiable auth is used after in the protectedRoute file where is detailed what to do if return false or true. but since is not getting this value from the API at time, this ProtectedRoute is not working as expected.

Comment: Can you provide more information about this ProtectedRoute component?
In theory, it should react to the "auth" prop when it changes.

Comment: const ProtectedRoute = ({ auth, component : component, ...rest})=>{
    return(
        <Route {...rest} render = {props => (
           auth ?
           <component {...props} />     
           : <Redirect to="/accessDenied" />     
        )} />
    );
}

Comment: That is the component ProtectedRoute and it works as expected depending if receive the Auth as true or false, but since from the prueba component the auth is send always as false because the api is called after the page is loaded.

Comment: I think the issue is this <Redirect .../>. Right after the page is loaded we have auth = false, because the effect which calls the api had not been called nor returned any value to the state, but <Redirect />, but redirect acts on this auth value (which is false) right away and redirects the user to the /accessDenied page. You may want to add another prop to the ProtectedRoute component to indicate that the page is still waiting for the API, then the component should not act based on the value of auth yet.

Comment: Hi Lucas, thanks for your answer. At the end I solved by setting the usestate value as empty array [], and then the Call to the API is executed before the component render.